# Import command fails when repository is used as a submodule

Tags: python, importerror

Sorry, I know it's a overasked topic but I'm pretty new to these stuff and didn't understand.
I have a repository with the following structure:

```
    repo_name/
           func_folder1/
                     func_file1.py -> func_1()
           func_folder2/
                     func_file2.py -> func_2()
```

func_2() exploits returned values of func_1() so I use the

```
    from func_folder1.func_file1 import func_1
```

command line inside func_file2.py to make everything work... and it works.
Now, I have another repository "repo_name2" where I need many services from "repo_name", so I added the latter as a submodule. Unfortunately an error arises:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func_folder1'
```

If I change the import to

```
    from ..func_folder1.func_file1 import func_1
```

it works in the repo_name2 but not in the repo_name. Seems pretty annoying to change it every time. Any idea?

(Python 3.9.7, Windows 10)

Comment: maybe try adding empty `__init__.py` files to the respective directories from where you want to import

Comment: @joAschauer unfortunately it doesn't work anyway